# php form retaining values on back button

Tags: php, forms, back

I have a small form which retains the form fields when the form is submitted

```
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php print $_POST['name']; ?>" />
```

The problem is that when the user hits the back button the values are retained.

Is there a way to clear the post variable and if not what is the best way to clear the fields ($name == '', $name == null)

Thanks

Comment: Browser stores the values of your previous page in cache.

Comment: im tinking of cleaning them with js

Comment: Why are you giving the input a value and a placeholder? By assigning a value, you'll never see the placeholder...

Comment: I think you are looking for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 0):

Use autocomplete="off" to disable the browser from populating the form input.